# Reduce submission time in LWC and Apex

Tags: salesforce, apex, lwc

I am utilizing 4 Lightning Web Components (LWC) in a parent component with a public URL. Users navigate through multiple tabs to fill out a form, and upon reaching the last page, they submit the form. However, the submission process takes more than half a minute due to numerous Apex calls and third-party API calls. I am seeking ways to optimize and speed up the submission process to reduce the overall time taken. Like I am using
The createRecordsOnSubmit() function sets a boolean flag isFormSubmitted to true and calls the createRecords() function.

In the createRecords() function, a variable params is assigned the result of calling this.getparemetersdetails(), and then converted to a formatted JSON string using JSON.stringify()

Subsequently, the createRecoordsOnFormSubmit() function is called with params as an argument using a promise. If the promise is resolved successfully with a result, the isLoading boolean flag is set to false, isFormSubmitted is set to true, and the getEncryptedTextContent() function is called. The result is then returned.
Below is the example: